# What does it mean to be within the standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

The average is $\frac {34.24}{57}$ = 60.07% and the standard deviation was $\frac{10.28}{57}$ = 18%

The value is $\frac{14}{57}$ = 24.56%. Which is above the level of standard deviation. Is this mean that the range of the all the values are from 18% to 82%? or most of the values are within 18% to 82%?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. $$60.07\% - 24.56\% = 35.51 \% \approx 60.07\% -  2\cdot 18\%$$ The value you are given is almost two standard deviations below the mean. 95% of all values will be within two standard deviations of the mean. So, 95% of the time: $$24.06\% = 60.07\%-2\cdot 18\% \le X \le 60.07\% + 2\cdot 18\% = 96.07\%$$

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some more details to this question. The average is $60.07%$, but $60.07%$ of what? Where did the expression $10.28/57$ come from? What do you mean by "above the level of standard deviation"? Where did you get the number $82%$ from? I'm guessing you got it by subtracting $18%$ from $100%$, but where did that formula come from? If you explain some of your reasoning, that'll help us explain these concepts to you.